# storing javascript and php in database and outputting it

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Okay I am at my wits end and hoping I can get a little help.
Trying to build a simple CMS and part of the CMS is to effectively store php and javascript/jquery in a pages table so that they can be retrieved to than be out put.

I have a function that serializes the form just fine and can firebug log the array going to the function. I cannot manage to store the javascript and php with the needed line breaks.

I tried mysql_real_escape_string but that just kills the content.
I tried htmlspecialchars and htmlspecialchars_decode...but need to use addslashes to get the query to to through.

Simplified example:
    html

```
<form>
<textarea name="pageDetails[php_html_Javascript_content]"></textarea>
</form>
```

jquery

```
<script>
function that ajaxes to a php function
function postForm()
{
var params = $('input[name="php_html_Javascript_content"]').serialize();
//custom ajax/posting function.
}
</script>
```

php Storing data

```
$pageDetails = $_POST['php_html_Javascript_content'];
function storePageDetails($pageDetails)
{
//heres where ive tried htmlspecialchars and mysql_real_escape_string
}
```

php echoing data

```
<php
$pageContent = getPageContentFunction();//just returns a simple array of the tables cells
$pageBody = $pageContent['pageBody'];
$pageBody = htmlspecialChars_decode($pageBody);
$pageBody = stripslashes($pageBody);
//I have tried a few ways but nothing seems to manage to out put the javascript as it //needs to with the line breaks
echo $pageBody;
?>
```

SO I guess I am just not sure how to get the javascript and php to store as it is typed into the textarea.

I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Few things to begin with - stop using mysql_* functions, as they are deprecated in newest versions of php, switch to mysqli_*. Also, your script is leaving itself wide open for sql injection, never assume data posted to your storing data script will be what you expect, or clean/safe.
Finally, to help answer your question, can you paste a sample of what it's outputting currently?  cheers :)

Comment: Try using `htmlentities();` on the whole text, it converts the linebreaks automatically if i remember right so you dont have to worry about anything.